# Python Sample App for BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm not able to locate the Tables that are part of this sample app: 
https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/browse/samples/python/appengine-bq-join/
Where can I find the actual Tables as they don't seem to be part the code downloadable from the above link?

Comment: It doesn't look like that sample expects a particular table. Where does it say the app comes with Tables?

Comment: The Wiki speaks about 'Top 100 SF and Fantasy According to NPR' and a tables/ subdirectory. Guess I was mislead by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the sample query used (from h[ere](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/browse/samples/python/appengine-bq-join/js/script.js)) is:

```
SELECT wiki_title.title 
FROM (SELECT title 
      FROM publicdata:samples.wikipedia 
      WHERE timestamp > 1262304000) AS wiki_title 
JOIN (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(word, r'\W', '') word, COUNT(*) 
      FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare 
      WHERE LENGTH(word) > 15 GROUP BY word IGNORE CASE) AS shakespeare_word 
ON wiki_title.title = shakespeare_word.word 
GROUP BY wiki_title.title LIMIT 10;"
```

The tables involved are `publicdata:samples.wikipedia` and `publicdata:samples.shakespeare`, both of which are public samples. They should show up when you open the bigquery [web UI](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com).